# Pic16F688 has no stable readings via buletooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, pic, android-bluetooth

I have spent much time trying to find out where is my mistakes while Im flashing the PIC16F688. The Pic has successfully flashed using PicKit2. Im using the Pic to convert analog pressure sensor to digital output and sending the data via Bluetooth, but the Bluetooth is not  receiving stable numbers of data. The data is consist of 4 character decimal number that is between 0 and 1023. 
The problem is that the Bluetooth can't wait at specific number and keep reading it, instead, it is reading  the 4 digits in random.

I think my mistake is within the configuration of internal oscillator. 
I'm attaching my code, the code is written to configure the flexiforce sensor circuit that outputs analog voltage up to 5v, and then the pic duty is to convert it to digital as I mentioned above.

it might be my wiring is not correct, please If you could help out with this one
and what configuration "at edit project" do I need to choose for Mikro PRO software?
I used "Bluetooth terminal" app to see my data asynchronous from Bluetooth. 
Thank you.

---

```
char *temp = "0000";
unsigned int adc_value;
char uart_rd; int i;
void main()
{
    OSCCON = 0x77;
    ANSEL = 0b00000100;
    CMCON0 = 0X07;
    TRISA = 0b00001100;
    UART1_Init(9600);
    Delay_ms(100);
    while (1)
    {
        adc_value = ADC_Read(2);
        temp[0] = adc_value/1000+48;
        temp[1] = (adc_value/100)%10+48;
        temp[2] = (adc_value/10)%10+48;
        temp[3] = adc_value%10+48;
        for (i=0;i<4; i++)
            UART1_Write(temp[i]);
        UART1_Write(13);
        Delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itoa` function to convert ADC integer value to characters for sending over `UART`. If there is error in calculation then you wont get appropriate value. Below code snippet for your reference :

```
while (1)
{
    adc_value = ADC_Read(2);
    itoa(adc_value, temp, 10);  
    for (i=0;i<4; i++)
        UART1_Write(temp[i]);
    UART1_Write(13);
    Delay_ms(1000);
}
```

Please check **Baud Rate** you have configured at both ends is same or not. If baudrate mismatches then you will get Random value at **Bluetooth Terminal** where you are reading values.

Comment: This is a good point, but it does not sound like the solution of the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found that I was feeding the bluetooth and pic a separate 3.3v. But when I connected them with my Flexiforce sensor (analog circuit that have opm), batteries (5V), I got stable reading. I don't know why, but it works,

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest, if you have a logic analyser, hook it up. If you don't recalculate your oscillator speed with the datasheet. It could just be that the internal oscillator is not accurate enough. What also works, is to write a function in assembly that waits a known time (by copy-pasting a lot of `NOP`s and using this to blink a led. Then start a stopwatch and count, say, 100 blinks. This is what i used to do before i had a logic analyser. (They are quite cheep on ebay).